# Why a variable when not declared in a function inside script tag doesn't give error "variable not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, function

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST PAGE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      "use strict";
      function a () {
        i = 0;
      }
   </script>
<body>
   <div> TEST </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why this html page is not producing "variable not defined" error when executed in browser, with `strict mode` enabled?

Answer (score 5):

Because you never execute `a` function.

Comment: But the script or the function will be compiled as soon as the html page will be loaded on browser. SO it should give the error. May be i am going in wrong direction. Can you please elaborate on the same.

Comment: @NehaGupta The script is not compiled. Javascript is an interpreted language. Only syntactical errors will be detected, not functional ones regardless of whether you use "use strict". JS Lint might warn you of this, but for the js engine, its all the same

Answer (score 0):

"use strict" Defines that JavaScript code should be ***executed*** in "strict mode" strict mode does not work at ***compile*** time. That's why it will only show error when your function is executed but you are not executing it.